# как подключить LiveData

Tags: android, livedata

настроил Room хочу подключить LiveData, но не понимаю как это сделать помогите пожалуйста разобраться

модель user

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;

}
```

userDao

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    User getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = :uid")
    User getByUid(int uid);

   /* @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    List<User> loadAllByIds(int[] userIds);

   /* @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
    "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")*/

    @Insert
    void insertAll(User user);

    @Update
    void update(User user);

    @Delete
    void delete(User user);

}
```

AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();

}
```

App

```
public class App extends Application {


    final String TAG ="myLog";

    public static App instance;
    private AppDatabase database;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        //Log.d(TAG, "help");

        instance = this;
        database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase.class, "database")
                .build();
    }

    public static App getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public AppDatabase getDatabase(){
        return database;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String TAG ="myLog";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        test();
        test1();
        test2();

    }


    // записывает данные в базу
   public void test(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            AppDatabase db = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
            UserDao userDao = db.userDao();

            User user = new User();
            user.uid=2;
            user.firstName ="dasf";
            user.lastName ="asdf";
            userDao.insertAll(user);


        }
    }).start();
}


   // читает данные из базы
    public void test1() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                AppDatabase db = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
                UserDao userDao = db.userDao();
                User user1 = userDao.getByUid(2);

               String vdf = user1.firstName;
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hel);
                textView.setText(vdf);
               // Log.d(TAG, vdf);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    // обновляет данные из базы
    public void test2(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AppDatabase db = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
                UserDao userDao = db.userDao();
                User user = new User();
                user.uid=2;
                user.firstName ="Alex";
                userDao.update(user);


            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: По идее надо просто типы возвращаемых значений поменять. Например так: `LiveData<User> getByUid(int uid);`. И у вас метод getAll по идее, должен падать, когда будет больше одного юзера в таблице. Наверное, вам там надо `List<User>` указать.

Comment: вешал наблюдателя так как вы написали в Dao, а при попытке подключить наблюдателя в активити выходит ошибка с которой не понимаю как разобраться, либо что то пишу неправильно в активити

Comment: Покажите в вопросе как пытались подключить и какую ошибку выдавало

Comment: не понимаю как обьявить такую строку в активити для моего примера `LiveData<String> liveData = DataController.getInstance().getData();` пишу так ` LiveData<User> liveData = UserDao.getByUid();` подчеркивает `getByUid`

Comment: Если я правильно понял что именно вы пишете (т.к. вы не полный код приводите) то должно получиться как-то так: `LiveData<User> liveData = App.getInstance().getDatabase().userDao().getByUid();`

Comment: все понял теперь, спасибо, раньше писал только  `LiveData<User> liveData = App.getInstance().getDatabase()` подчеркивало тоже щас дописал `.userDao().getByUid()` подчеркивать перестало и создался метод `onChanged`буду разбираться дальше.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, еще вот такой вопрос, как засетить данные в `LiveData` нашел уроки на сайте https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/525-urok-2-livedata.html там есть вот такой пример `private MutableLiveData<String> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
 
LiveData<String> getData() {
   return liveData;
}` я не понимаю где его писать если я не использую ViewModel

Comment: Тут не подскажу - не знаю. Если речь про LiveData, которая данные из БД берёт - то она обновлённые данные автоматически получит при изменениях в таблице, из которой берёт данные.